Chebyshev equation solved in two different ways gives two different bases, I can't match them for k=0
I solved the Chebyshev equation:
$$(1-x^2)y'' - xy' + k^2y = 0$$
in two different ways. First, by substituting $x=\cos\theta$, I reduced it to a simple equation with constant coefficients:
$$y''+k^2y = 0$$
which has a well-known solution in sines and cosines:
$$y = A\cos(k\theta) + B\sin(k\theta)$$
so substituting back, I got the following exact general solution for the original equation:
$$y = A\cos(k\cos^{-1}x) + B\sin(k\cos^{-1}x)$$
Then I solved it again using a different method (the power series method) and obtained the power series for the two basis functions (even and odd):
$$y_0 = 1 + \frac{(0^2-k^2)}{2!}x^2 + \frac{(0^2-k^2)(2^2-k^2)}{4!}x^4+ \frac{(0^2-k^2)(2^2-k^2)(4^2-k^2)}{6!}x^6 + \dots\\
y_1 = x + \frac{(1^2-k^2)}{3!}x^3 + \frac{(1^2-k^2)(3^2-k^2)}{5!}x^5+ \frac{(1^2-k^2)(3^2-k^2)(5^2-k^2)}{7!}x^7 + \dots$$
But then, when I tried the case for $k=0$, I got a puzzling rezult:
The exact general solution reduces to just:
$$y = A\cos 0 + B\sin 0 = A\cdot 1 + B\cdot 0$$
while the power series reduce to:
$$\begin{align*}&y_0 = 1\\
&y_1 = x + \frac{1}{3!}x^3 + \frac{9}{5!}x^5+ \frac{225}{7!}x^7 + \dots = \sin^{-1}x\end{align*}$$
which I identified as the inverse sine, as you can see.
But this is a problem! From the power series solution we see that the inverse sine is a possible solution to the Chebyshev equation in the k=0 case (it is, I checked by substituting it back to the equation), but this solution cannot be obtained from the "exact" general solution when k=0, because setting k=0 degenerates the basis to just a one-dimensional space of constants, and the inverse sine (again, a valid solution) clearly doesn't lie within this space! :P
What's the deal here?
Why does the "exact" solution break down for the k=0 case and fails to express all valid solutions?
I thought that all bases are equivalent, as long as they're orthogonal, and they can be converted one into another. But I don't see how I could convert them in this case.
Does it have something to do with the fact that for k=0 the function-term drops out from the equation? (So it's kinda similar to those singular solutions where for some combination of parameters the terms with derivatives drop out from the equation, but I didn't know that it could also happen when the function term drops out?)
And how can I fix this to catch all solutions? (The power series solution doesn't seem to have the same problem.)
How can I match these two bases with each other or convert one into another?

When $k=0$, the solution to $y''(\theta)+k^2y(\theta)=0$ is $y(\theta)=A+B\theta$. To obtain this result as the limit $k\to 0$ of $y=A\cos(k\theta)+B\sin(k\theta)$, replace $B$ with $\tilde{B}/k$ before taking the limit.

Why the limit though? Can't I just use the reduced (constant-coefficient) ODE in $\theta$, which  for $k=0$ is just $y''=0$, and substitute back $\theta = \cos^{-1}x$ in it to get the full basis that contains this solution? (By the well-known identity $\cos^{-1}x = \frac{\pi}{2} - \sin^{-1}x$, so it contains my inverse sine as well.)

Yes, you can. ${}$
